# PHP - How do I hide certain posts from being called?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, lets say I have a forum and it has two tables, one is called **posts** and the the other is **users**. When someone visits the site, all of the posts from table **posts** are called. If I have a user temporarily banned and I wanted to hide all of their posts (or if there are multiple users in this case), how can I call the forum posts and not show their posts? I already have a column in my **users** table called *active*. Active is just 1 or 0 for banned or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

your question is very vague but assuming the following table structures:

```
table users
    id  username    password    active
table posts
    id  userid      title       text        date
```

I would use the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.text, p.date FROM posts AS p INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.userid AND u.active = 1;
```

now i'm not SQL guy and there may be errors here.. i'm sorry i'm not going to set this all up to test. if you cannot figure it out from my example feel free to comment and we can investigate further. more can be read on mysql JOIN syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

edit: as was pointed out to me, INNER JOIN is the correct JOIN to use.

Answer (score -2):

Make another field in your table that is a flag. Say 1 for show and 0 for no show. Set it up so when you ban someone it runs through the post table and finds all their post and sets the flag to 0. When showing post use a select * from table where show field =1 in your mysql_query, assuming your using mysql.

Comment: Why set a flag on every post, when you can just link from the 2 tables, something like: `post.userID` to `users.active` ? What rlemon said in the comments above.